# How To Resize Drop Down Menu Bar In Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

How to resize drop down menu bar in `Tkinter`?

I tried using `padx` or `pady` to resize but it doesn't work.

I want my list menu to look like this:

[image]

Comment: How does the dropdown menu look now?

Comment: no padding.............................

Answer (score -1):

You can use the .place() to change its width and height

```
OptionMenu.place(x=10, y=10, width=200, height=350)
```

Comment: The OP isn't using an `OptionMenu`

Comment: What do you mean by OP?

Comment: `OP` can mean "Original Post" (the question being asked) or "Original Poster" (the one asking the question)